# Proof that mirror coupling is maximal coupling

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, stopping-times

In this [link](https://sites.math.northwestern.edu/%7Eehsu/CouplingNewVersion.pdf) p3, I read that the mirror coupling of Brownian motion is actually a maximal coupling. However, they do not prove this and I was wondering if anyone might have a reference to a proof of this fact.

To be more specific, I am asking for a proof that:
$$P\{T(X1, X2) ≥ t\} = \phi_t(|x1 − x2|)$$
where $T(X1, X2)$ is the earliest
time at which the two Brownian motions from the mirror coupling coincide and where $$\phi_t(r)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \int_0^{r/2}e^{-\rho^2/2}d\rho$$
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $\phi_t(r)$ gives the tail probability of the first passage time of a 1D Brownian motion as they say on the first page (and whose proof is a direct application of reflection principle), i.e. $P(\tau_{r/2} \geq t) = \phi_t (r)$
- You can reduce the hitting time of an n-dimensional Brownian motion to an n-1 dimensional hyperplane to the hitting time of a one-dimensional Brownian motion by spherical symmetry and essentially discarding all the directions orthogonal to the normal vector of the hyperplane. In particular, if an n-dimensional Brownian motion starts $r = |x_1 - x_2|/2$ away from the hyperplane, the distribution of its hitting time $\tau$ will be given by $P(\tau \geq t) = \phi_t (|x_1 - x_2|)$
- $T(X_1, X_2) = \tau$, since as soon as $X_1$ and $X_2$ coincide on the hyperplane, they will stick together, so we just need to look at the first time $X_1$ hits the hyperplane, which is given by $\tau$, and thus they share the same CDF.